# cannot do asqueryable on mongodb collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I got two models, a User and a Team as below:

```
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Password:")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Confirm:")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email:")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Username:")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Firtname:")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Lastname:")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Country:")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "City:")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Birthdate:")]
    public int Birthdate { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }


   [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId TeamID { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int LeagueID { get; set; }

    public List<Player> Player { get; set; }
```

So I've created a user but now I want to add teams to my user.
This is the code I'm using:

```
  var databaseClient = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.FantasySportsConnectionString);
  var server = databaseClient.GetServer();
  var database = server.GetDatabase("Users");
  var collection = database.GetCollection<User>("users");

  var user = collection.AsQueryable().First(o => o._id == Session["ID"]);

  user.Teams.Add(new Team { TeamID = new ObjectId(), TeamName = "Some Team" });
```

But when I do this I get these errors:

1: `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection<SportsFantasy_2._0.Models.User>' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`

2: `'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection<SportsFantasy_2._0.Models.User>' does not contain a definition for 'AsQueryable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: `AsQueryable` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` not `MongoCollection` you will have to create one or perhaps there is a linq extension class for Mongo already

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing a namespace, `MongoDB.Driver.Linq`, simply add that at the top:

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

That specific method is:

```
LinqExtensionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<T> AsQueryable<T>(this MongoCollection<T> collection);
    //...
}
```

Comment: I added that but now it says: 
Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' and 'object' 

on the line    var user = collection.AsQueryable().First(o => o._id == Session["ID"]);

Comment: @DanielGustafsson That's a different problem altogether. Indeed _id is of ObjectID and Session["ID"] is an object. If you're sure it's actually an ObjectID then cast it: o._id == (ObjectID)Session["ID"]

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error with with the .NET driver v2.3.0. I removed it and installed v2.2.4 using NuGet and it worked. The error I kept getting:
Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.Linq.IMongoQueryable`1<!!0> MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollectionExtensions.AsQueryable(MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection`1)'.

Comment: I got the same error with you when I upgrade to 2.3.0, and I change back to 2.2.4, it works again. May be this is a bug with version 2.3.0.