# Need a simple count of a collection with specific criteria

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need a count  of a collection where username is "john".

There's no .where or .asqueryable.... nothing!

here is my code so far:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
var mDB = client.GetDatabase("TempTables");
var collection = mDB.GetCollection<waveWorksheetForDB>("waveWorksheet");
```

How do I write a query that will return a count with the above mentioned criteria?

mongoDb driver: 2.0.1

Comment: show your `waveWorksheetForDB` class

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/reading/

Answer (score 0):

Just `CountAsync`

```
var count = await collection.Find(x => x.Name == "John").CountAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

if  mDB.GetCollection("waveWorksheet") returns a collection, then you should have the .Cast<>(). 
That will return an IEnumerable and you will be able to use normal Linq

```
var collection = mDB.GetCollection<waveWorksheetForDB>("waveWorksheet");
int count = collection.Cast<waveWorksheetForDB>.Count();
```

Answer (score -2):

Per [cannot do asqueryable on mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174897/cannot-do-asqueryable-on-mongodb-collection), you are missing a namespace.

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

Comment: I tried adding assembly, but it doesn't show up in intellisnce

Comment: @boruchsiper The new driver doesn't have linq yet.